# What is a basic Citrix setup?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-control, citrix

I have a Windows laptop, local Win7 server, and two Linux servers (remote); what is wanted - a high-speed remote desktop without VNC/X problems (either are slow).

Which Citrix's components will allow to get highspeed remote desktop access to all those machines?

What are benefits of other possible solutions (XenDesktop) over plain VNC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use XenApp, which allows use of individual programs running remotely on the server, but appearing as though it is local (Windows Server 2008 and R2 can do this natively - 'RemoteApp').  Xenapp can also stream applications to the local machine, allowing them to be run using local resources, while not actually being installed locally.

Anyway, XenApp is not cheap and I do not think XenDesktop is either.  Before you go into that sort of thing, you should try using [**NoMachine NX or FreeNX**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology).

Comment: Does either XenApp/FreeNX drops a running process, if client gets disconnected? That would be unwelcome.. about the pricing, well, one always can try to talk his boss into buying a company-wide license for product X (assuming that there is a friendly boss).

Comment: @mhambra: No they don't, but I think you can make XenApp drop it if you wanted - it has a lot of different options.  BTW, I don't think Citrix works on Linux servers anyway (but there are clients).  There's a UNIX version of XenApp, but I think it is very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [FreeNX](http://freenx.berlios.de/).

"NX is an exciting new technology for remote display. It provides near local speed application responsiveness over high latency, low bandwidth links. The core libraries for NX are provided by NoMachine under the GPL. FreeNX is a GPL implementation of the NX Server and NX Client Components. "